# PhpStorm 8 - can't enable emmet feature

Tags: emmet

In PhpStorm, I'm trying to get the emmet feature to work.

I went through Google and found this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/enabling-emmet-support.html

Here, they tell me to enable the feature in Settings and then to use keystrokes like "tab" or "space" or "enter"  which I've found to be already enabled and I've tried all those options, but it's not actually working.

How is this to be solved?

Answer (score 0):

In PhpStorm Preferences you have the Emmet section. There you can check to enable the XML/HTML Emmet. Afterwards, you can type emmet syntax like : `div.text` and press TAB. You will get : `<div class="text"></div>` .

Regards,
Adrian

See this link [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfGiM.png)

Comment: surely, I'd tried that 100s of times, but it seems to not work...wht other solutions available? plz help...thanks in advance